# Selenium webdriver "Error communicating with remote browser. It may have died" when I run test in parralel

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on client side. I have created around 150 test scripts. But during execution, after some script execution, Selenium throws below error and it close the browser. Time is not a fix for this error. It comes when I am executing all the test scripts together in parallel.

The error shows on Google Chrome and Firefox browsers. I am using *selenium-server-standalone-2.26.0.jar* file and doing execution on FF 13.0.1 version. I have also tried with FF version 14, but I get the same error. My client is not happy with this error because we dont have workaround for this issue.

```
  **Error message:**
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died
```

Comment: Since you said you are running in parallel, did you make sure that webdriver object is threadsafe?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will happen when you dealing with popup window.

**Example**

- Working on main window clicking on something leads to open a new popup
- switch the control to popup window & do your operations in pop-up
- Most of the cases popup will be closed automatically after some action performed in it. (EX : Login with facebook option most of site now a days, after entering user credential no need to close that popup it will be closed automatically after submitting proper credentials)
- After this you need to switch the control to main window again otherwise it will throws above exception.

I think your doing some operations without having the control over a window.

Comment: Hi Santosh thanks for reply but in those test cases i am not playing with popup windows.

Comment: [testng] System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1'
, java.version: '1.7.0_07'
   [testng] Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
   [testng] Error in caught doCommand: windowFocus
   [testng] [SeleniumCommandLogger] - Executing findElement parameters: {"using"
:"name","value":"current screen shot"}